# Datatable binary installation not working in PyCharm

Tags: python, datatable, pycharm, runtime-error, apple-m1

I am on Apple Silicon and I was not able to install datatable. So I cloned and build a wheel from their gitrepo(as mentioned in their docs).

`pip3 install git+https://github.com/h2oai/datatable`

The libraries show that I have datatable installed but when I try to run a script it fails with message:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datatable'`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UP2T.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnmD0.png)

I have tried uninstalling and installing it again but this is not helping.

Thanks in advance!

I was trying to run a script that uses datatable for aggregation operations.

Comment: Don't post images of code or error messages - copy or type the text into the question, using proper markdown formatting (see stackoverflow guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Give more details about your coding environment : are you using a venv / conda env, etc. ?

Comment: Have you checked that the python interpreter used for syntax checking by the IDE (is showed in the bottom of you screen in the bar. Pycharm show the libraries installed for that interpreter) is the same you are using to execute your script? (in the "edit configuration" near the play button you see the python interpreter you are using)